# SQL STUFF() function keeps escaping my HTML

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the tutorial here:

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/06/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row.html

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF( (SELECT '<li>' + CountryCode + '</li>' from Country  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Codes FROM Country
```

This works great, but all my HTML is now encoded (i.e. `&lt;li&gt;`)

Is there a way around this?  Using a SUBSTRING() approach does this also.

Comment: It's XML entitisation - not `stuff`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `'<li>' + CountryCode + '</li>'` to `CountryCode as li` and you will probably get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

it is because XML PATH makes it xml safe so `<` becomes `&lt;`

try

```
DECLARE @CountryCode VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @CountryCode = ''
SELECT  @CountryCode = @CountryCode + '<li>' + CountryCode + '</li>' from Country 

SELECT @CountryCode
```

example

```
DECLARE @CountryCode VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @CountryCode = ''
SELECT   @CountryCode = @CountryCode + '<li>' + name + '</li>' 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'a'

SELECT @CountryCode
```

you can also of course use the `REPLACE` function to replace `'&lt;`' to `'<'`

In my opinion adding `li` should be done  at the front end and not in the database

Comment: +1 - thank you for clarifying on the XML PATH conversion, I should have figured that out.